Перенос строк, сложение строк
tile  +=  f'<Representation bandwidth="53445" width="445" height="111">\
                <EssentialProperty schemeIdUri="http://dashif.org/thumbnail_tile" value="10x5"/>\
            </Representation>'

Как сложить строчки так, чтобы был перенос строк. На выходе получаю как одну строчку...

Если Вам нужно создать определенную структуру текста с переносами и отступами, то возможно проще всего будет использовать тройные кавычки:
tile = f'''\
<Representation bandwidth="53445" width="445" height="111">
    <EssentialProperty schemeIdUri="http://dashif.org/thumbnail_tile" value="10x5"/>
</Representation>
'''

Обратный слэш в самом начале поставил для более удобного редактирования - без него будет засчитан перенос. Иначе нужно писать с самой первой строки, где объявляется переменная.
При сложении с другими строками можно обратный слэш убрать (например, если в предыдущей не был прописан перенос строки):
tile = '<Body>'
tile += f'''
<Representation bandwidth="53445" width="445" height="111">
    <EssentialProperty schemeIdUri="http://dashif.org/thumbnail_tile" value="10x5"/>
</Representation>
'''

Ну либо можете использовать базовый вариант - спец.символ \n для переноса строки:
tile = '<Body>\n'
tile += f'<Representation bandwidth="53445" width="445" height="111">\n\
    <EssentialProperty schemeIdUri="http://dashif.org/thumbnail_tile" value="10x5"/>\n\
</Representation>'

